# I'm using Spring MVC and JSON to do some tasks, and i've got this exception

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jpa, persist

I've been searching for three days, and my error still exist, I've tried a lot of solutions without any positive result !

I've ManyToMany relations, and here is my JPA mapping :

@Entity
public class Facteur implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long idF;
```

.....

```
@ManyToMany
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinTable(name="Affectation",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="IdF"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="idT"))
private List<Tournee> tournees;
```

.......

}

"Tournee" Class is like this

@Entity
public class Tournee implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int idT;

....
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="tournees")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<Facteur> facteurs;
```

....

}

here is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getFacteur/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Facteur getFacteurById(@RequestParam("id") Long idF) {
    Facteur f = facteurService.getById(idF);
    System.out.println(f.toString());
    return f;
}
```

and JQuery code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".updatelink").click(function() {
            var facteurId = $(this).data("facteur-id");
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "http://localhost:8080/distribution/facteur/getFacteur/",
                data : { id : facteurId },
                success : function(data) {
                            alert('SUCCESSS');
                            },
                error : function(){
                            alert("ERROR");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Any solutions ?

Best regards !

Comment: GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/distribution] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag[0]->ma.pm.distribution.entities.Tournee["facteurs"]->org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag[0]->ma.pm.distribution.entities.Facteur["tournees"]-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the two sides of the relationship should not be serialized in order to avoid the infinite loop that causes your stackoverflow error. You can use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to avoid the error:

```
//class Facteur
@ManyToMany
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinTable(name="Affectation",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="IdF"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="idT"))
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Tournee> tournees;
```

```
//class Tournee
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="tournees")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JsonBackReference
private List<Facteur> facteurs;
```

Add the `@JsonManagedReference` in the forward part of the relationship which you want to serialize, and add `@JsonBackReference` in the back part of the relationship which will not be serialized. In fact, if you serialize a Tournee instance to JSON, you will **not** get the Facteur array instance. To avoid this drawback, just use the simple `@JsonIgnore`, but keep in mind, that therefore getters and setters will be ignored during serialization.

Comment: U wanna say that I've to use the three annotations u've described at the same time ? Cuz i've  aleardy done JsonManagedReference JsonBackReference but without any results !!

Comment: Yes, you can use the annotations mentioned above at the same time. Please take a look on this [blog](http://keenformatics.blogspot.de/2013/08/how-to-solve-json-infinite-recursion.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into stackoverflow error since Facteur class has reference to tournees and Tournees in turn refers to Facteur - circular refernce while JSON serialization.
Just add `@JsonIgnore` annotation to `private List<Tournee> tournees;` declaration in `Facteur` class and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, I've already tried it, and it doesn't solve the issue for me !!

Comment: interesting, what library are you using for json serialization.. like jackson/gson etc.. and post the complete stack trace in the question

Comment: It worked after a lot of tests, Thank u so much, I've used what you said